# Angular not recieving data from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a Rails / Angular application, with a factory.

The Rails application is correctly running the first get, but the data is not making it back to the Angular app for some reason. The same queries work from the api.

```
angular.module('assaypipelineApp').factory 'Primer3Output', ($resource) ->
  $resource('/api/batch_details/:batch_detail_id/primer3_output',
        {batch_detail_id: '@batchDetailId'},
        {update: {method: 'PATCH'}})

angular.module('assaypipelineApp').factory 'Primer3OutputPair', ($resource) ->
  $resource('/api/primer3_outputs/:primer3_output_id/primer3_output_pairs',
        {primer3_output_id: '@primer3OutputPairId'},
        {update: {method: 'PATCH'}})
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :batch_details do
  resource :primer3_parameters
  resource :primer3_output
end
resources :primer3_outputs, only: [:show, :update] do
  resources :primer3_output_pairs, only: [:index, :update]
end
```

**angular controller**

```
$scope.invokeAssayModal = (assay_id) ->
  $scope.assay_id = assay_id
  $scope.primerPairs = {}
  $scope.primer3Output = Primer3Output.get({batch_detail_id: $scope.assay_id}) 
  console.log("xxx1")
  console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.primer3Output,null,' '))
  console.log($scope.primer3Output.id)
  console.log("xxx2")
  $scope.primerPairs = Primer3OutputPair.query({primer3_output_id: $scope.primer3Output.id})
  console.log("xxx")
  console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.primerPairs,null,' '))
```

**console output**

```
] PanelController.js?body=1:178
xxx1 PanelController.js?body=1:380
{} PanelController.js?body=1:381
undefined PanelController.js?body=1:382
xxx2 PanelController.js?body=1:383
xxx PanelController.js?body=1:387
[] PanelController.js?body=1:388
```

**Rails console**

```
Started GET "/api/batch_details/15337/primer3_output" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-27 21:33:29 +0100
Processing by Api::Primer3OutputsController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"batch_detail_id"=>"15337"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  BatchDetail Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "batch_details".* FROM "batch_details" WHERE "batch_details"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "15337"]]
  Primer3Output Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "primer3_outputs".* FROM "primer3_outputs" WHERE "primer3_outputs"."batch_detail_id" = $1 ORDER BY "primer3_outputs"."id" ASC LIMIT 1   [["batch_detail_id", 15337]]
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 1.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)


Started GET "/api/primer3_outputs/primer3_output_pairs" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-27 21:33:29 +0100
Processing by Api::Primer3OutputsController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"id"=>"primer3_output_pairs"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find BatchDetail without an ID:
```

**APIs via the browser**

These return a json object with the correct data, so the api is working.

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/batch_details/15337/primer3_output

http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/primer3_outputs/412/primer3_output_pairs
```

Comment: Is is possible the PATCH is causing it not to return? If you're loading it in the browser, it is not using PATCH.

Comment: @rncrtr Thank you for your comment. It's been a while since I raised this issue, and have since started using Restangular for all http calls. I can't actually remember how I resolved it, but the code has been completely re-written.